# How do I get the current time as a TimeStamp in Kotlin?

Tags: time, kotlin, timestamp

This is the timestamp format I need: 2018-03-22 19:02:12.337909

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't have any time handling classes of its own, so you just use Java's `java.time`.  For an ISO-8601 timestamp (which is the preferred format):

```
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now())
```

That will return `2018-04-16T17:00:08.746Z`.  For your format, or if you need a different timezone, you can specify those:

```
DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .format(Instant.now())
```

See the [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for details on how to specify a format string.

The *java.time* classes are bundled with Android 26 and later, and with Java 8 and later. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

**Update 2020/07**

The development of ThreeTenABP is winding down. With Gradle plugin 4.0 and higher, you can directly use java 8 APIs without requiring a minimum API level for your app.

For more information see [Java 8+ API desugaring support (Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

Comment: This requires API lvl 26 or above, any compatible alternative with older APIs?

Comment: Oh yes, @DarkCygnus. For Android API level under 26 use the Android adaptation of backport of java.time. See [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 60):

```
  val currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Comment: This won't give you the format op requested. `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a long, not a formatted string.

Comment: maybe this is not the answer to this question, but when I search "timestamp in Kotlin"  this is the best answer, so upvote

Comment: I don’t get how so many upvotes to this answer. Clearly the question said the required time stamp in the expected format. Which  System.currentTimeMillis() does not return

Comment: There are many kinds of timestamp, but (correctly or not), often the convention when using the term is to refer to a _numeric_ timestamp. That's probably why this answer is upvoted, because people just google "timestamp in Kotlin" and end up here

Answer (score 36):

Try `java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())` i'm using API 19 and it works for me

Comment: Is it java.security or java.sql?

Comment: import java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: The terrible `java.sql.Timestamp` class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Replaced by `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` classes. Suggesting the use of `Timestamp` in 2019 is poor advice.

Answer (score 7):

First get the

```
val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
// currentTimeMillis = 1674411796305
```

Then get TimeStamp like this

```
val timeStamp = Timestamp(currentTimeMillis)
// timestamp = 2023-01-22 20:23:16.305
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [kotlinx.datetime library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime). Here's how:

```
val currentTime = Clock.System.now()
println("The current time is $currentTime")
```

will print the current time in this format:

```
2023-02-28T07:43:04.618714Z
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.mkyong.date
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
object TimeStampExample {
    private val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss")
    @JvmStatic fun main(args:Array<String>) {
        //method 1
        val timestamp = Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
        println(timestamp)
        //method 2 - via Date
        val date = Date()
        println(Timestamp(date.getTime()))
        //return number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
        println(timestamp.getTime())
        //format timestamp
        println(sdf.format(timestamp))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this

`val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())`

and here you have all Date and Time patterns
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Of course my bad for not mentioning Android Project use. I found this line of code in developer android documentation,it's simple and working for me so i thought it was fine. Sorry.

Comment: Please note that Kotlin is much more than Kotlin on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options

```
// method 1
val currentTimestamp =System.currentTimeMillis()

// method 2
val currentTimestamp =Instant.now().toEpochMilli()

// method 3
val currentZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
val currentTimestamp = currentZonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()

// method 4
val currentTimestamp = Clock.System.now()
```